# Dynamic nid for drupal_field twig tweak function

Tags: theming, 9

I have a field_slides paragraph field on my home page, on drupal 9.1.3. It is for rendering a carousel.
I want to iterate over the elements of the paragraph field (eg the slides with title, description and button fields). I'm using drupal_field twig tweak function for the sake of translability.
I have tried something like the following :

```
  {%  for slide in element['#items'] %}
     <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.index0 == 0 %}active{% endif %}">
     <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ file_url(slide.entity.field_illustration[0].entity.fileuri) }}" alt="First slide">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block w-50">
     <h5 class="carousel-title" onload="animateCarouselTitle(ev)">{{ drupal_field('field_titre', 'node', {{ slide.entity.nid }}) }}</h5>
     <p class="carousel-bouton">{{ drupal_field('field_bouton', 'node', {{ slide.entity.nid }}) }}</p>
     <p>{{ drupal_field('field_corps', 'node', {{ slide.entity.nid }}) }}</p>
     </div>
     </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

Any idea on how to dynamically get the nid of the paragraph entity in the `drupal_field` function?

Comment: In Drupal 9 nodes are identified by "id" key, not by "nid".

Comment: Are you per chance looking for the `paragraph id` or are you truly looking for `NID`, i.e. the `node id` which as above commenter mentions is now `id` in D8 & 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking away the curly brackets from around {{ slide.entity.nid }} so it's:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_corps', 'node', slide.entity.id) }}
```